# Create files with python with .lst and .hex extensions

Tags: python, file, hex

I need to create two files using python, one with .lst extension and another with .hex extension. Are these two formats supported by Python? and if they are, what is the process to create them?
And once they are created, how do I open them or read them? Do I need a specific program or should I show their contents using python?

Comment: You can create a file with any extension you want, and put whatever you want into it, python doesn't care. Eg.: you could take an image, read the binary jpeg data, and save it as monthly_reports.xls. python and most other programming languages don't care about filenames - they're just labels to some data on the disk.

Comment: File *extensions* don't actually matter to python. You can write anything you want to a filename ending in `.hex` or `.lst`. What should concern you is the file *format*.